# Vue - how to use an event handler to invoke functions from sibling/child

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

> **NOTE:** I am using Laravel as the backend framework

I'm trying to create a more reactive way of adding items to a list where I wouldn't need to call server on an added list item.

I've seen other people's code where they prefer to write in `window.location.reload();` so the page would reload after each submit showing the new row, so that's 2 calls: the async Post call + reload page, seems less reactive and costly IMHO.

Since the user is already adding items, it be smarter to render those lines in the front, while saving to DB via an Async Post, thus cutting server calls by 50%?

To summarize, I am trying to achieve the following:

- when user adds item to list in `AddComponent`, display that item in `GetComponent` **without reloading**.

I've read about events on Vue, I'm trying to use `Vue.mixin({})` with an `eventBus` to wrap an event helper for all components under `app.js`, yet not fully clear how this would work with what I want to do above.

#### Here's the code, used pastebin links for brevity:

[`app.js`](https://pastebin.com/nPmG7UW6) - Main

[`AddComponent.vue`](https://pastebin.com/RyUmzZwg) - Saves item to model

[`GetComponent.vue`](https://pastebin.com/umC4UBRg) - Gets all items from model, inside AddComponent

Thanks,
Bud

Comment: Please paste the code here, we don't like having to sift through multiple pages from a questionable source

Answer (score 0):

Typical way of [handling sibling communication is to use an event hub](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced), as you mentioned. It could be implemented in a number of ways.

One would be using a mixin, but you probably don't need it. There is a [simpler way of adding instance variables](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example).

Demo below shows how such variable (representing an event hub) could be added and how it would be used to perform communication between sibling components, including the usage of Axios for an ajax (POST) request.

```js
Vue.prototype.$hub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub

Vue.component('get-component', {
  template: "#get-comp",
  data() {
    return {foo: 'initial foo'}
  },
  created() {
    this.$hub.$on('update', (eventData) => {
      this.foo = eventData;
      this.someMethod(eventData); // can also call methods
    });
  },
  methods: {
    someMethod(arg) { console.log('someMethod of get-component called with', arg); }
  }
});
Vue.component('add-component', {
  template: "#add-comp",
  methods: {
    addCoin() {
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', { // just a demo POST
        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1
      }).then((response) => {
        this.$hub.$emit('update', response.data);
      });
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<template id="get-comp">
    <div>my foo is {{ foo }}</div>
</template>

<template id="add-comp">
    <div><button @click="addCoin">Click to emit foobar event</button></div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <add-component></add-component>
  <get-component></get-component>
</div>
```